# Discovering the depth and count of tables on an HTML page with Perl

Tags: html-parsing, perl-module, html-table

I have local copies of  numerous downloaded web-pages. The pages almost certainly have only a few different types of table layouts, but before looking to extract data, I first want to print out the depth and count of the tables that exist on each page.

Using `HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => $d, count => $c )` I can iterate over a reasonable range of `$d` and `$c` until I get nothing ... a method that works but looks so obviously bad that I'm sure there is a much better way. Please, should I be using a different module than HTML::TableExtract, or is there something more sensible that I should be doing with TableExtract?

Such are the problems of being an infrequent user of Perl but being sure that it's the right tool for a particular job!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that my question grew out of my complete misunderstanding of how to use the `count` and `depth` arguments in `HTML::TableExtract->new()` . All the examples I had seen used either the `headers=>` argument, or else a combination of `depth=>` and `count=>`. In fact, neither argument is necessary. What I really needed was to use

```
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
```

without any arguments to the `new()` method, and then to use  `$te->tables_report()` to give me exactly the kind of list that I was looking for.

No wonder I didn't get any answers!